# $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}$ has an inverse $\implies a,c$ have inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, linear-transformations

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. For $a,b,c\in R$,

$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & c 
\end{pmatrix}$ has an inverse $\implies a,c$ have inverses?

(an inverse of a matrix $M$ means a matrix $N$ such that $MN=NM=I$.)

I got there exist $x,y\in R$ such that $xa=1,cy=1$.
But I am not sure if $ax=1,yc=1$.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: $R$ may not be commutative.

Comment: A sort of generalisation of Dieudonné's  determinants for skew  fields?

Comment: Multiply you matrix inverse on either side of the matrix to get left and right inverses for $a$ and $c$. Then there is a theorem that if you have both left and right inverses, then the element itself is invertible.

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler. You don't even need that last step! Oops.

Comment: I don't see how you reached your conclusion $xa=1,cy=1$. If your matrix has a left inverse, that implies $xa=yc=1$; if it has a right inverse, that implies $ax=cy=1$. Neither case matches your statement. And by the way, is the inverse of your matrix a left inverse or a right inverse (or both)?

Comment: ${\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
0 & c 
\end{pmatrix}}^{-1}$=${\begin{pmatrix} 
d & e \\
f & g 
\end{pmatrix}}$ and $f$ must be $0$?

Comment: In a non-commutative ring, the left and right inverses of a matrix $M$ can be different. So $M^{-1}$ is not well defined. Please tell us what you mean.

Comment: By an inverse for a matrix $M$, I meant a matrix $N$ such that $MN=NM=I$. I am sorry. I should edit the qustion now.

Comment: @TonyK: if an element $x$ in a ring has both a left inverse $\ell$ and a right inverse $r$, then $\ell=r$: $\ell = \ell 1 = \ell(xr) = (\ell x)r = 1r = r$. So your assertion that “the left and right inverses of a matrix $M$ can be different” is false. It is true that $M$ can have one but not the other, but if it has both, they are equal and they are the inverse.

Comment: @TonyK What *is* true is that in a noncommutative ring, you can have an element with several right inverses (or several left inverses) so that the notion of "the" right inverse (or "the" left inverse) is not well-defined. Of course, such an element would not have any inverses on the other side.

Comment: user682705: It's me who should apologise! It's a good thing @ArturoMagidin came along to set me right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that $a$ and $c$ are not invertible.

HINT:

Consider a invertible linear transformation $\phi$ with an invariant subspace $W$ so that the restriction $\phi_{| W}$ is not invertible. (Clearly $W$ has to have an infinite dimension.) For this, take a bijective map $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ with an invariant subset $M$ so that $f_{|M}$ is not surjective. (Eg: $f(z)=z+1$, $M = \mathbb{N}$).Now linearize everything.

In our example $R$ will be the ring of square matrices $(a_{ij})_{ij \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}}$ with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ such that in every column there are finitely many non-zero entries. Therefore, $R$ is isomorphic to ring of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})} $.

Comment: $a$ and $b$? You mean $a$ and $c$? Of course the $R$ you propose contains one-sided invertible elements... but how do you know a $2\times 2$ invertible matrix such as the user describes exists with one-sided invertible elements on the diagonal?

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question.

Comment: Take $V= \mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}$.  Take $R= End_{\mathbb{R}}$ .  Now consider an isomorphism of $V\oplus V$ that invariantes $V\oplus 0$ but the restriction to it is not an isomorphism. You can see $End_{\mathbb{R}}(V\oplus V)$ as $M_{2\times 2}(R)$.  Also, thank you,  it is $a$ and $c$, corrected that

Comment: I don't have any issue with the claim you made, I'm just trying to see why you think it can be used to produce an invertible matrix with noninvertible elements on the diagonal.  That's presumably why you gave this $R$ to use.  I could be missing something obvious, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

A more explicit form of the above counter example: Consider a space of bounded one-sided sequences $X=\{(x_0,x_1,x_2,...)\}$ and let $R$ be the ring of bounded linear operators on $X$. Now let
$$ a(x_0,x_1,...)=(0,x_0,x_1,...),$$ $$ b(y_0,y_1,...)=(y_0,0,...),$$ $$c(y_0,y_1,...)=(y_1,y_2,...) $$

You may then verify that $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} c & 0 \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$. It is a way of decomposing a full shift into one sided shifts.

Comment: That is very nice.  If the supporting space is the $l_2$ one, then the full shift is an isometry, so the inverseis the transpose. ($b$ is self adjoint, $a^t = c$)  Great!

Comment: indeed, nice obsrvation